# Windows Server 2008 File Sharing for users in Administrators group

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing, groups

Ok here is probably dumbest question but I really dont understand how sharing works.

I shared a folder with name "Data" and I gave permission to "Administrators" group to everything in Network Sharing Permissions.

On the folder "Data", apart from the usual permissions, I gave "Administrators" group full control to "Data" folder.

Now I added a user in Local Users with name "DataUser" and I made this user member of "Administrators".

Simply:

1. LAN Server (No Active Directory, No Domain, Standalone Server)
2. We access via IP address.
3. "DataUser" is User and is member of "Administrators"
4. "\Server\Data" is shared folder with "Administrators" group being full rights
5. "Data" folder has full control for "Administrators" group
6. I also did "Replace all permissions on child objects" for "Data" folder

Now the problem is, I am on other machine, I can add a new file inside "\Server\Data" folder but i can not delete or overwrite the files which are there right from beginning.

Entire Data folder and its all files have full control of "Administrators" group then why user "DataUser" which is in "Administrators" group cant delete existing files? The newly added files can be deleted but not the old ones. If I right click, I can see old file has full control for "Administrators" group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is a byproduct of the [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) being enabled.  The UAC basically filters away your Adminisrator access to protect you from yourself.

You can either choose to disable it, or you can choose to add yourself to another group, and use another group when you are setting up filesystem/share access.

Comment: To see the effects of this, start a regular, non-elevated command prompt, and run the command "whoami /groups".  Any group described as "Group used for deny only" is not a candidate for granting permissions for use by a non-elevated program such as Windows Explorer.

Comment: Thanks, I understood it, but is there anyway to not disable UAC and make the groups work correctly as they were working correctly in 2003? By doing this, on remote desktop, we get UAC prompt but every other software fails like you cant unzip files, you cant do anything even if you belong to administrators group. However if we add user to the file ACL, then it works, but cant do that for every user. It becomes too much to manage.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2526083