# Good tool to delete folders which are read only/need "Administrator"

Tags: windows-server-2008, filesystems

I did a system state backup of my server onto my second physical hard drive.

This is fine, but I cannot delete the folder because some sub folders require admin permission (I am admin with full control) and some are read-only.

Is there a good, powerful tool that can delete unwanted files regardless of it being read-only or anything like that?

Thanks

Comment: Almost sounds like you are seeing the effects of the [UAC](http://serverfault.com/questions/63271/windows-server-2008-file-sharing-for-users-in-administrators-group/73341#73341) filtering away your permissions.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a separate tool.  Just go in and make yourself owner (right-click the folder -> Properties -> Security tab -> Advanced button -> Owner tab).  Make sure to check "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects".

Once you are the owner, give yourself full rights to the folder, and then you'll be able to delete everything.