# Failure to copy files with ownership/ACL information on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, permissions

I'm attempting to copy a directory tree, maintaining its ownership information using the command:

```
XCOPY S:\ProjectsDefault\Template\admin S:\Projects\00\111\admin /S /E /I /O
```

the command gives an `Access denied` error message, and while it does create the directory tree, the ownership and ACL information is not copied.

This is being done on a Windows 2008 R2 Server which has mounted a share from a Windows 2003 R2 domain controller. The user has been been granted full access to the share and is a member of the `Domain Admins` security group.

Oddly enough, the command does work if performed on a different (Windows 2003 R2 Server). (It also works if done using the Domain Administrator account on the 2008 server.)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running your command shell as Administrator?  Some of your privileges will be [filtered away by the UAC](https://serverfault.com/questions/63271/windows-server-2008-file-sharing-for-users-in-administrators-group/73341#73341).

Comment: I was hoping to be able to grant the approriate rights to the user, rather than use the Adminsitrator account - the odd thing is that it only seems to fail on the 2008 server, so I suspect there is something I'm missing with my security setup.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like robocopy more than xcopy. Robocopy is a bit more robust., and also has better logging capability.
The command you will need to use will be like this then:

```
robcopy "S:\ProjectsDefault\Tempalte\admin" "S:\Projects\00\111\admim" /e /copyall
```

See here for more information about robocopy.By the way isn't there a spelling mistake in Tempalte (instead of Template)
[Robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Robocopy is quite useful, though it also has the same issues - I used `/COPY:DATSO` rather than `/COPYALL`. (Fixed the spelling mistake, but that was only a transcription error.)

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting? Have you also checked that you have the approriate permissions on the source and destination?

Comment: `Access Denied`. I have permissions to create the files/directories; indeed there are no error messages if I do an `XCOPY /S /E /I`.